# X11 forwarding, how to force audio to the host?

Tags: ssh, fedora, pulseaudio, sshd, xforwarding

i am connecting from a laptop:

```
$ uname -a
Linux fedora 5.11.18-200.fc33.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 3 15:05:29 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

to a single-board-computer:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mobian 5.10-sunxi64 #2 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 12 09:55:56 UTC 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

over SSH with compressed X11 forwarding:

```
ssh -YC user@mobian
```

everything seems great except for the fact, that audio plays in the laptop and I want it to play in the remote machine. how is this achieved?

---

P.S. I suspect this is something fedora-specific as the same `ssh -YC user@mobian` connection from a different device:

```
$ uname -a
Linux sxmo 5.11.0 #1-postmarketos-allwinner SMP Sat Mar 27 14:48:00 UTC 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

leaves the audio-output on the remote machine.

---

**EDIT** based on comments:

locally on fedora:

```
[user@fedora ~]$ xprop -root | grep PULSE
PULSE_COOKIE(STRING) = "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"
PULSE_SERVER(STRING) = "{f5e96850fbf948e19c0eba4f100fa72a}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native tcp:fedora.localdomain:4713 tcp6:fedora.localdomain:4713"
PULSE_SESSION_ID(STRING) = "2"
PULSE_ID(STRING) = "1000@f5e96850fbf948e19c0eba4f100fa72a/1985"
```

remotely on mobian without `-YC`:

```
user@mobian:~$ xprop -root | grep PULSE
xprop:  unable to open display ''
```

remotely on mobian with `-YC`:

```
[user@fedora ~]$ ssh user@mobian -YC

...

user@mobian:~$ xprop -root | grep PULSE
PULSE_COOKIE(STRING) = "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"
PULSE_SERVER(STRING) = "{f5e96850fbf948e19c0eba4f100fa72a}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native tcp:fedora.localdomain:4713 tcp6:fedora.localdomain:4713"
PULSE_SESSION_ID(STRING) = "2"
PULSE_ID(STRING) = "1000@f5e96850fbf948e19c0eba4f100fa72a/1985"
```

locally on mobian:

```
user@mobian:~$ xprop -root | grep PULSE
PULSE_COOKIE(STRING) = "8139d0fdc04752954ff9018ca4006d741d1b8aef9ed8fdd041184fda6080bad0fbf0e0ca00ecc6eacd5b4adde99d84ac33932773da3b8dd99a2adaeb085cd622daefbd75ab193690185f856457ac9541a1e4075a8217484df1bd136d00bc6c0c80abef6e3ee86daed144c33fece49cd9a896c3bb7dcb6520441f21c48a7f045693d9d6e47e2f7bc32ce6ce4b958df2842f8d7298d690e48a1343fbed5310fa50475acaf928047802978cf0f417502c298332b56e5a66a75b97e9ddb59a739e4d34c8f63fbb7ce883b35ed115c44639db11d5e543665978dfcbe43b5d8d41677ee68195c153103986283d80b2ce3239559f12d2928b9ffb05054e3cca70ff277d"
PULSE_SERVER(STRING) = "{e5ca38bfe5be445f838be0328a1c5f33}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native tcp:mobian.localdomain:4713 tcp6:mobian.localdomain:4713"
PULSE_ID(STRING) = "1000@e5ca38bfe5be445f838be0328a1c5f33/615"
```

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to produce audio on the remote machine? If it's just the terminal beep (e.g. `echo -e '\a'`), the remote system just outputs a "bell" character and the terminal emulator on your local system decides how it is presented: some audible sound, a visual notification ("visible bell") or nothing at all.

Comment: audio is played per web-browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward sound over VNC?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138350/how-can-i-forward-sound-over-vnc)

Comment: I think the specific tools on mobian pick up the information available through fedora's xprop root display to use remotely pulseaudio. As I don't have a tool doing this (it's related to mobian more than fedora here), I can't test if that's really what happened. I believe the answer(s) is there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/607820/how-to-disable-pulseaudio-remote-sound/607827#607827 . Try `xprop -root |grep PULSE` to get an idea (this should work the same if run remotely through ssh or locally: get local display information). I also don't know what channel would be used to tunnel through.

Comment: @A.B: result of ```xprop -root | grep PULSE``` on fedora and from ```ssh -YC user@mobian``` added

Comment: Both display "tcp:fedora.localdomain:4713" in the results. Like if pulseaudio is advertising this, but I wouln't know more on the subject.

Comment: ok. thanks! it is leading to the right direction. I'd like it to say ```tcp:mobian.localdomain:4713``` as it does locally.

Comment: If you install paprefs - an addon for pulseaudio, you can setup  pulseaudio to stream audio with a direct connection when you establish your X11 forwarding.  Unfortuantly, I don't remember how to do it - I know it works on debian so it should work on any linux.

Comment: @CinaedSimson: thank for the hint! I'll try ```paprefs``` out, do I need it on both host (single board computer, where I want the audio output) and client (laptop, from where I ```ssh -YC```), or just in one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the solution is described here:
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#xforwarding

it's all about the `PULSE_SERVER` "variable". So starting a process with `PULSE_SERVER=localhost` appenden before ensures the audio protocols run on the host machine. In my case the single board computer and not the laptop.

I have only had the chance to test this once, so I am not sure it works on all scenarios but here it is:

```
[user@fedora ~]$ ssh user@mobian -YC

...


user@mobian:~$ PULSE_SERVER=localhost [YOUR_APLICATION]
```

I'll try to update if I get more information.